# How to forecast and fit the optimal model for multiple time series?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I want to do batch forecasting among multiple series, for example, if I want to forecast time series with IDs that end with 1(1,11,21,31...), how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide an example table of the data that you hope to be able to use in a model like this. This might mean making up several fake time series, getting them into an R data.frame object, and then using `dput()` to provide the sample data to us so we can test. I am not sure what you mean by "forecast time series with IDs that end with 1" --- and without a sample data set I cannot even try to answer your question. Since a model for forecasting is a fairly complex "output," I would say that "how can I do that?" is not a great question. It is too open ended to "answer".

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide detailed information, I was not sure which forecasting method you want to use hence I give here an example of a univariate time series model:

Load required packages:

```
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)
```

We use example data from Rob Hyndman:

```
dta <- read.csv("https://robjhyndman.com/data/ausretail.csv")
```

Now change the column names:

```
colnames(dta) <- c("date", paste0("tsname_", seq_len(ncol(dta[,-1]))))
```

Select timeseries which end with 1:

```
dta_ends_with1 <- dplyr::select(dta, dplyr::ends_with("1"))
```

Create a ts object:

```
dta_ends_with1 <- ts(dta_ends_with1, start = c(1982,5), frequency = 12)
```

Specify how many steps ahead you want to forecast, here I set it to 6 steps ahead,

```
h <- 6
```

Now we prepare a matrix to save the forecast:

```
fc <- matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(dta_ends_with1), nrow = h)
```

Forecasting loop.

```
for (i in seq_len(ncol(dta_ends_with1))) {
  
fc[,i]  <- forecast::forecast(forecast::auto.arima(dta_ends_with1[,i]), 
                              h = h)$mean
  
}
```

Set the column names:

```
colnames(fc) <- colnames(dta_ends_with1)

head(fc)
```